# What all are the built-in data types available in IDA?

Tags: ida, hexrays

Hex Rays decompiler assigns weird looking data types to variables, e.g. `__int64`. How do I get to know what all are the built-in data types available in IDA?

Answer (score 2):

The C types in IDA Pro seem to ressemble the Visual C++ syntax.

Read an article written by Hex-Rays
https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1361.shtml

The primitive types that you must know:
bool, char, __int8, __int16, __int16, __int32, int, __int64, __int128

you add a keyword 'unsigned' before in the beginning to make the value unsigned.

Comment: And the <defs.h> header file from the hexrays sdk defines those types, so you can (with some luck) re-compile the output of hexrays.